# How do I most quickly delete an entire row/column from an array?

Tags: matlab

E.g. I want to turn a 360x160 array into a 360x159 array.

Comment: just do `A(:,colnum) = []` or `A(rownum,:) = []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select only the rows you need:

```
a = ones(360,160);
b = a(:,1:159);
size(b)
ans =

   360   159
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to delete the column, as @jucestain suggested. If you want to preserve the original array, then duplicate it and delete from the duplicate. @Molly's solution is slightly slower.

```
>> tic; a=ones(360,160); a(:,160)=[]; toc
Elapsed time is 0.001409 seconds.
>> tic; a=ones(360,160); b=a; b(:,160)=[]; toc
Elapsed time is 0.001827 seconds.
>> tic; a=ones(360,160); b=a(:,1:159); toc
Elapsed time is 0.004002 seconds.
```